# Entity Framework 6 add existing complex type to key columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm working on a project using EF 6 built using database-first approach. There are several tables that previously had the same 3 properties mapped to a complex type (used in several places throughout code). These properties were designated as "foreign key" columns, although their parent-child relationships were never defined in the database.

Recently, a co-worker went through and formally defined the relationships between the FKs and their parent tables in SQL Server.  I am now attempting to update the entity model (update from database), and the new associations did not appear.  I have resorted to removing the tables from the model and re-adding them. They now show the proper associations.

However, the mapping to Complex Type is gone.  When I try to add it back, the updated mappings destroy the associations on those properties (I get a model error when saving). I am aware that Complex Types do not support associations.

Is it recommended to first remove the associations for the columns prior to re-mapping them to the complex type? Will EF observe the underlying key relationship even though the columns are not visible on the entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I would still like to get some feedback on my questions, here's what I did to solve my issues.

1) Removed the associations generated by EF when deleting and re-adding tables from the database.  Note that these relationships are only for the foreign key fields which were to be replaced by the complex type.

2) Followed the MS steps (found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680147(v=vs.113).aspx)) to refactor the requisite key properties to a complex type

3) Optional: It was necessary for me to edit the EDMX directly as XML in order to remove some lingering associations that could not be repaired with the designer

So far, my model functions as intended.  I believe the FK relationships are observed during CRUD operations.